# getCalendarById where the ID is a String

Tags: google-apps-script

On a Google Spreadsheet there are several calendar IDs.  Each is in Column B, and is in the format of "SuperLongStringGoesHere@group.calendar.google.com".

Things work when I manually enter the calendar ID instead of using a variable (the variable is calRngVal).  When I use a variable, it returns null.  How do I call getCalendarById using a variable?

```
var calRng = calids.getRange(a, 2);
var calRngVal = calRng.getDisplayValue();
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calRngVal);
var ad = cal.getName();
```

Thanks in advance!

Here is a picture of the debugger:[image: debugger]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special to access a calendar using a string value stored in a sheet. Both your approach and that mentioned in Simon's answer should work.

There must be something else going wrong.  Are you sure you have permission to access all of the calendars listed in the sheet? If you don't have permission, getCalendarById will return null.

Wrap the code after your getCalendarById call in a try/catch block so that one "bad" calendar won't crash the script.

EG:

```
var calRng = calids.getRange(a, 2);
var calRngVal = calRng.getDisplayValue();
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calRngVal);
try{
   var ad = cal.getName();  
   //other code here
}catch(e){
   Logger.log('Exception processing '+calRngVal+', row '+a+'. Message: '+e);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Also note that looping and fetching the ranges one by one is a slow way to do this, you could use getDataRange() to return all the data in the sheet in a two dimensional array, then just loop over the array.  However I would fix the "null" problem before optimizing.

Comment: You were correct.  I needed to have some of the calendars shared with the account from which I was executing the script.  Thanks to both you and Simon.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the code is selecting a cell with a calendar id value in it? Try this:

```
var calRng = calids.getRange("A1:B");
var calRngVal = calRng.getValues();
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calRngVal[1][1]);
var ad = cal.getName();
```

If it doesn't work, try using the logger sometime:

```
Logger.log(calRngVal);
```

Comment: Yes, the cell has a calendar id value in it.  When I watch the debugger, it shows that calRngVal has a string, surrounded by quotes."7o5jcphfb102oa1hhl99hn80s4@group.calendar.google.com"

Comment: Behind Google Apps Script there's just a Javascipt interpreter doing it's work. For it there is no difference between a variable String and just directly entering a String. Have you tried the code I provided?

Comment: Hi Simon, Yes, I tried it and I get the same error.  I'm going to try and attach a picture of the debugger so you can look at what it is showing.